# InnoDB performance implications of one 3 column index VS three 2 column indexes

Tags: mysql, performance, index, innodb, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB with InnoDB but this would apply with MySql as well.

I have a list of records that belong to categories and would like to order them by 3 different criteria.

I have come up with two approaches for the table schema and indexing.

**Approach 1**

```
CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` MEDIUMINT NULL,
  `nosql_document_id` VARCHAR NULL,
  `sort_criteria_1` MEDIUMINT NULL,
  `sort_criteria_2` MEDIUMINT NULL,
  `sort_criteria_3` MEDIUMINT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `idx_cat_sc1` (`category_id` ASC, `sort_critetia_1` ASC),
  INDEX `idx_cat_sc2` (`category_id` ASC, `sort_critetia_2` ASC),
  INDEX `idx_cat_sc3` (`category_id` ASC, `sort_criteria_3` ASC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Query for each sort criteria would look like this:

```
SELECT id FROM document WHERE category_id = 1 ORDER BY sort_criteria_1 LIMIT 50,50;
SELECT id FROM document WHERE category_id = 1 ORDER BY sort_criteria_2 LIMIT 50,50;
SELECT id FROM document WHERE category_id = 1 ORDER BY sort_criteria_3 LIMIT 50,50;
```

**Approach 2**

```
CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` MEDIUMINT NULL,
  `nosql_document_id` VARCHAR NULL,
  `sort_criteria_id` TINYINT NULL,
  `sort` MEDIUMINT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `idx_cat_combo` (`category_id` ASC, `sort_criteria_id` ASC, `sort` ASC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Query for each sort criteria would look like this:

```
SELECT id FROM document WHERE category_id = 1 AND sort_criteria_id = 1 ORDER BY sort LIMIT 50,50;
SELECT id FROM document WHERE category_id = 1 AND sort_criteria_id = 2 ORDER BY sort LIMIT 50,50;
SELECT id FROM document WHERE category_id = 1 AND sort_criteria_id = 3 ORDER BY sort LIMIT 50,50;
```

With 1 Million documents I would need 1M records in first approach, and 3M records in second approach, which uses:

*Approach 1*: 129M total table size.

*Approach 2*: 193M total table size.

Assuming I will not need more than 3 sort criterias:

**Questions I have:**

1. Can I assume that Approach 1 is better in speed because of overall smaller data and index size?
2. Would it make sense to have covering index here so that nosql_document_id is always in clustered index? (id, nosql_document_id)
3. Are there any better approaches to accomplishing above that I should consider? I could not think of a way to have a clustered covering index including ordering. Is there a way?

**UPDATE 1**

It would probably make sense to replace `Approach 2` with following:

**Approach 3**

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE TABLE `list` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sort_criteria_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `idx_combo` (`category_id` ASC, `sort_criteria_id` ASC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `list_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nosql_document_id` VARCHAR NULL,
  `sort` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `idx_combo` (`list_id` ASC, `sort` ASC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

However this till does not address the issue of having 3 duplicate records for same data as @rick-james correclty points out. It feels like it comes down to flexibility to add new sort options in Approaches 2 and 3 vs more constrained but effective method of Approach 1.

Further investigating size implications, I can tell that index size itself is almost identical, between approach 1 and 3. Only the size of data grows 3x due to primary id replicated. I wonder how this affects memory usage in innodb buffer. I do want all my indexes to be drawn from memory, does this mean that in terms of memory the approaches are same, and the difference is only in disk usage?

Here's results:

```
show table status from approach1;
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
| Name     | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
| category | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |    100 |            163 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |            101 |
| document | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 943703 |             39 |    37289984 |               0 |     83558400 |   6291456 |        1000001 |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

show table status from approach3;
+----------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
| Name     | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows    | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
| category | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |     100 |            163 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |            101 |
| document | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 2986718 |             33 |    99205120 |               0 |     79314944 |   5242880 |        3000001 |
| list     | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |     300 |             54 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |            301 |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic database principle is to avoid duplication of data.  Option 2 has 3 rows with essentially the same basic data.  So, a vote for Option 1.

Option 1 is smaller overall, so another vote for it.

If you get much past 3 sorts, the problem gets messier.

You are doing `SELECT id`.  Was that a simplification for this discussion?  If you really are selecting only `id`, then we should discuss that inefficiency.

"Covering" should always be *considered*, but since your queries do not mention `nosql_document_id`, there is no need for it to be in the index.  (This harks back to my previous comment.)

A composite secondary index *starting with* the `PRIMARY KEY` is almost always useless.

Is some combination of columns unique and not-null?  If so, can you get rid of `id`?  If so, then this entire discussion changes.

Comment: Thanks for valuable feedback Rick. I've added third option, but it really does not differ much from second one and does not address the issues of duplicate data you so correctly raised. any of the columns that query would order by will not be null but also will not be unique. I could not possibly use sort order as part of primary key, as the sort colums will be updated often. However category_id, and nosql_document_id combinations will always be unique. But that does not seem to make sense to use a primary clustered key (category_id, id ) as my main query will use order by sort fields.

Comment: Rick, if we had to have the flexibility for more sorting options, does approach 2 or 3 make sense? Can these be improved in any way? Are there any other solutions to this problem worth considering?

Comment: Mr. James, I just checked out your profile. I can't believe a MySql legend like you is giving me advise, I'm so excited! I deleted the duplicate in stackoverflow as you suggested and now am enjoying your awesome blog. WOW what amazing advice there. I love it.

Comment: @Jimbotron - `NOT NULL` is required for the PK, but not for `INDEX` or `UNIQUE`.  `NULL` values sort 'first'.  The PK provides the ordering of the data, which may help in performance (cf "clustering").  Before discussing "more sorting options", please indicate the datatypes and number of sorting columns.

Comment: @Jimbotron - Another issue...  If the `SELECT` will be returning a million rows, what will the client do with it?  (A resultset of a million rows is actually a rarety.)  Or does `category_id` whittle down the resultset significantly?

Comment: @Jimbotron - About 100 categories?  About 10K rows in a resultset?  Still rather large.

Comment: I failed to mention that each select query would include offset and limit, so the results would be returned as a page at a time. Probably about 50 results at a time, so: `0, 50` or `50, 50` or `100, 50` and so on. Basically resulting in ordered list by sort and 50 items at a time. I'm going to edit query in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking me regarding data types and NOT NULL. Any of the sort fields (sort_criteria_* or sort depending on schema) would never be NULL, they would always have some integer value. Number of sorting columns would be 3 but sorting would always be done by any one of them not all three or any combination of. I would like to find best solution for A. only 3 sorting fields. B. Unlimited sorting by single sort column and "list_id". Also important to note: any of the three sort fileldscould be updated regularly.

Comment: @Jimbotron - See my blog on pagination; it points out the flaws an inefficiencies of using `OFFSET`, and it provides an alternative.  Approach 1 still looks good.